# Difference between BitmapFactory.decodeFile vs decodeStream

Tags: java, android, bitmap, stream, bitmapfactory

If we have a `File` by the name of `f`, is there any real difference between

`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f))`

and

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Here is the entirety of the `decodeFile()` method, from [the now-current source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java):

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName, Options opts) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(pathName);
        bm = decodeStream(stream, null, opts);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /*  do nothing.
            If the exception happened on open, bm will be null.
        */
        Log.e("BitmapFactory", "Unable to decode stream: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing here
            }
        }
    }
    return bm;
}
```

It is not materially different from what you or I would do.

Comment: Interesting to see empty catch statements in official Android source code; I always heard this was questionable practice

Comment: Yeah, I would have logged it to LogCat, at least. That would be one benefit of using `decodeStream()`.

Comment: And so many people wondering why it returns null without any warning.

Answer (score 0):

`decodeFile()` gets a filename and decodes the image from there. `decodeStream()` accepts an `InputStream`, which can be anything besides a file. For example, you can fetch the data from a network connection, or from a zip file without first having to extract the file.

If you just have a file it's easier to just use `decodeFile()`.

Comment: If `f` is strictly a `File`, `decodeFile()` will not work, as it only accepts a filename (`String`). You will need to get the filename. That being said, I don't think there is any practical difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. Using the decodeFile() method, you can't manage the FileNotFound exception, while using the decodeStream() method, you can.

So, if you are sure your file will be loaded, you should use decodeFile(). Otherwise, you should initialize the FileStream manualy and use the decodeStream() method.